# Dropdown wont work after installing UI React scaffolding

Tags: reactjs, laravel, dropdown, laravel-jetstream

Recently, I tried to install UI React Scaffolding on my new Laravel Jetstream application.
I did the usual stuff and installed the UI React scaffolding for my app. The React example works fine but somehow I noticed that the dropdown for logout button on my navbar is unresponsive and doesn't work.

I tried to trace what causes it but not sure what it is, since all of the .js files is still loaded to the application. Have anyone faced this kind of issue?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

May you perhaps share a code snippet in case you have an error somewhere and we can assist.